# Why does Reduce give False on SameQ with its copy-pasted result?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

If I evaluate

```
Reduce[#, x] & /@ {{4 x > 1, 2 x < 5}, {5 x > 1, x < 5}, {4 x > 1, x < 5}}
```

the result is

```
{1/4 < x < 5/2, 1/5 < x < 5, 1/4 < x < 5}
```

If I select the result and copy-paste it on a new line (that is, I am not typing by hand the inequalities) to compare it with `SameQ`

```
(Reduce[#, x] & /@ {{4 x > 1, 2 x < 5}, {5 x > 1, x < 5}, {4 x > 1, 
     x < 5}}) === {1/4 < x < 5/2, 1/5 < x < 5, 1/4 < x < 5}
```

I get `False`

Why is that so?

In particular, I found that out when using `Length` on the expressions

```
{Length /@ (Reduce[#, x] & /@ {{4 x > 1, 2 x < 5}, {5 x > 1, 
      x < 5}, {4 x > 1, x < 5}}), 
 Length /@ {1/4 < x < 5/2, 1/5 < x < 5, 1/4 < x < 5}}
```

which, surprisingly to me, leads to different results

```
{{5, 5, 5}, {3, 3, 3}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Reduce` is returning `Inequality` objects, which let's you mix inequalities like `a < x <= b`.

Typing `a < x < b` gives a `Less` object.

```
FullForm[Reduce[#, x] & /@ {{4 x > 1, 2 x < 5}, {5 x > 1, x < 5}, {4 x > 1, x < 5}}]
```

> ```
> List[Inequality[Rational[1,4],Less,x,Less,Rational[5,2]],Inequality[Rational[1,5],Less,x,Less,5],Inequality[Rational[1,4],Less,x,Less,5]]
> ```

```
FullForm[{1/4 < x < 5/2, 1/5 < x < 5, 1/4 < x < 5}]
```

> ```
> List[Less[Rational[1,4],x,Rational[5,2]],Less[Rational[1,5],x,5],Less[Rational[1,4],x,5]]
> ```

---

A simple example to see where `Inequality` comes in handy:

```
FullForm[a < x <= b]
```

> ```
> Inequality[a, Less, x, LessEqual, b]
> ```

But using only `<` is interpreted as `Less`. I imagine Reduce always returns `Inequality` objects for consistency.

```
FullForm[a < x < b]
```

> ```
> Less[a, x, b]
> ```

Comment: But I am not typing it. I literally copy-paste the output. Why is its form not preserved? Is that a common feature of Mathematica?

Comment: When you copy it's copying the plain text, not the underlying FullForm.

Comment: This is not common in Mathematica, it's a corner case I think.

Comment: I don't quite grok Chip's last comment, but the lack of a canonical representation of inequalities is one of the mildly irritating design choices of the language (at least for me).

Comment: I agree, I'd prefer if `Reduce` returned `Less`, etc when possible. Or even have `Inequality` auto evaluate where possible.